3” water heater vent into a 2 story brick chimney. Reducing 8” steel to 4” through roof?
I have a 3” vent from gas water heater in the basement venting into a 2 story brick chimney (nothing else vents into the chimney). In the attic there is an 8” round steel flue through the roof. Can I reduce the 8” steel flue to 4” steel flue through the roof?
I haven’t been able to get to it but the fittings look like double wall.


Probably since not reducing below the 3 inch.  Flue sizes are usually controlled by local regulations and the maker of of the heater.  Cleaning of the flue is important also.  Almost impossible to clean the 8 inch section with a 4 inch section above it.

is it 8"  on the inside or is it double-wall steel.

In general, it's a bad idea to reduce a duct in the direction of flow. I can't cite code, but I probably wouldn't do it.
